# Active record destroy give me "Can't dup NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, null

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.5 and I am getting this weird message "Can't dup NilClass" when I try to run the code below

```
rr = Node.find(params[:id])
puts rr.inspect
rr.destroy
```

The application prints out the correct information about the node, when I try to do the exact same thing in script/console it works fine!!! I have no clue what is going on ..

I upgraded my application to rails 2.3.8 but no luck what so ever :(

Please help,

Edit:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2184:in `dup'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2184:in `scoped_methods'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2188:in `current_scoped_methods'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2178:in `scope'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1543:in `find_every'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1505:in `find_initial'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:613:in `find'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/has_one_association.rb:80:in `find_target'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:239:in `load_target'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:112:in `reload'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1250:in `acl'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1460:in `send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1460:in `has_one_dependent_destroy_for_acl'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `evaluate_method'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:276:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:344:in `callback'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:336:in `destroy_without_transactions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:228:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:192:in `destroy'
/home/wael/public_html/app/models/node.rb:355:in `destroy'
```

Wa'el

Comment: What's the stack trace ?

Comment: Do you have a default scope on node?

Comment: The application executes everything in the "destroy" definition in node model before it stops on "super" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possibly somehow confusing your Node class with this one?
http://apidock.com/ruby/REXML/Node